# Limit ScrollView Scroll Size until click a button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have scroll view added to the storyboard and Constraints are sets. top of the scroll view there are some another `UIView` will be displayed according to the button user gonna click. some `UIViews` Height are small and some of heights are almost the size of the `ScrollView`. in initial page load i want to restrict scroll to specific height(small Height). after user click for the bigger `UiView` `scrollview` come to its original size.

i have tried like below in `ViewDidLoad`

```
CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0, self.scroller.contentSize.height - 295);
[self.scroller setContentOffset:bottomOffset animated:YES];
```

but its not working. always scrolling through entire screen. and it shows empty area in bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I did it my self.
you need to get the outlet of the Vertical Space to Bottom Layout from the ScrollView.

and in the ViewDidload. `self.scroller.constant = [Any Number];`

and when button click again `self.scroller.constant = [Any Number];`